# xpath fails to return head of the html document

Tags: html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am trying to read this link  `http://www.aspemail.com` with the `HtmlAtiligtyPack`. But it fails to read the the head section and returns null.

```
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string download = webClient.DownloadString(linkDetails.Url);

        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(download);
        HtmlNode htmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html/head");
```

but when I check with breakpoints placed then the htmlNode contains null. Is this procedure ok I am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SelectSingleNode("html/head");
```

Have you looked at the source of this site? There's no `<html>` node in it. There's only a closing `</html>` at the end but the source directly starts with a `<head>` - OMG, it's incredible what kind of people are writing websites nowadays.

You could adapt your selector like this:

```
HtmlNode htmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("head");
```

Comment: I checked with the opera and there is html node in it.

Comment: I checked with Google Chrome and there isn't a `<html>`. Since you are using a WebClient and haven't specified a `User-Agent` request header I guess that the site doesn't return a `<html>`. One possibility would be to send the User-Agent of opera to trick the site into thinking that it is accessed by Opera and eventually render the `<html>`. Or simply adapt your selector: HtmlNode `htmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("head");`.

Comment: Ok so how to work for this discrepancy. As I have to read random pages and I can't guess the structure of the document in each page.

Comment: `htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("head");`.

Comment: or can't do it for each browser because the it is upto users wish which browser do the use..

Comment: You might contact the authors of the website you are trying to scrape and ask them to fix it as well.

Comment: This like I am giving users the ability to store the book marks and the summary of the link like facebook for review.. so in this case its upto me to fix things in code only

Comment: Or if I use  SelectSingleNode("head or html/head").. is it ok?

Comment: It is OK if the website is guaranteed to always have a `<head>` section. Given the quality of the designers of this website, this is not something I would rely on :-)

Comment: So what should I do for maximum reliabilty.. To me it also seems like very fragile way to read the html that is not guaranteed to be well formed